# Ruby on Rails - inconsistency when needing to reload model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I found something which seems a bit confusing to me being new to Rails. I was told I need to do `reload!` in the console whenever I made a change in the model.

Let's assume I call `reload!` before these two senarios.

Let's say I have scenario A, with a model with a specific syntax error as such:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  validator :title, presence: true
end
```

Running `Article.new(title: "Test 1")` will throw a `NoMethodError`, as it understandably would. But if I then go in and fix the error, even if I don't run `reload!`, running `Article.new(title: "Test 1")` works now.

Scenario B, going in the opposite direction. I have a model with the correct syntax as such:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :title, presence: true
end
```

Running `Article.new(title: "Test 1")` will work with no error, as it should. But if I then go in and change `validates` to `validator`. If I don't run `reload!`, running `Article.new(title: "Test 1")` still works despite the `article.rb` file having a syntax error. It isn't until I run `reload!` explicitly that I now get a `NoMethodError`.

What's exactly going on here? I know it's very specific, but I don't see why this would be the case. It seems like sometimes you have to run `reload!` to update the model (like scenario B) and sometimes, like in scenario A, you don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first example, Rails was not able to load the class because it raised an error. After fixing the error there was no need to class reload because the class was not loaded successfully before.

In your second example, the class was loaded successfully. Therefore you need to call `reload!` to tell Rails to reload the class into memory.

Comment: Ah! Thank you! So it will basically automatically reload upon next execution if it doesn’t succeed the first time?

Comment: @rb612 Yes. In development mode, Rails do not load all the constants by default. It loads them on-demand when referenced anywhere. So, if it encounters `Article`, it will check if this constant is loaded in memory, if not, it will check the presence of file in `$LOAD_PATH`, if found, it will try to load it and will create a constant `Article` with the said code. In first case, since the latter part failed, `Article` constant was never created, so when you fix the code and do `Article.first` again, it will load the class correctly with updated code.